# Memory leak with Backbone

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks

I have a little js app with Backbone, and almost every part does not leak any memory (except from the caching). But Chrome dev tools show that one page leaks about 0.2 MB on the js heap each time it is called. Will that cause problems in any browser, or is it necessary to remove such a small leak?

Comment: How often will the page be called?

Comment: Well, depends on the user, but normally not more than 5 times.